# jQuery tabs are shown and hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following configuration:

```js
var pageone = document.getElementById("pageone"),
    pagetwo = document.getElementById("pagetwo"),
    pagethree = document.getElementById("pagethree"),
    bfpone = document.getElementById("buttonone"),
    bfptwo = document.getElementById("buttontwo"),
    bfpthree = document.getElementById("buttonthree");
$(pagetwo).hide();
$(pagethree).hide();
$(bfpone).click(function () {
    $(pageone).show();
    $(pagetwo).hide();
    $(pagethree).hide();
});
$(bfptwo).click(function () {
    $(pageone).hide();
    $(pagetwo).show();
    $(pagethree).hide();
});
$(bfpthree).click(function () {
    $(pageone).hide();
    $(pagetwo).hide();
    $(pagethree).show();
});
```

```css
.page{
    background:red;
    color:white;
    margin:2em;
    padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttonone">Btn one</div>
<div id="buttontwo">Btn two</div>
<div id="buttonthree">Btn three</div>
<div id="pageone" class="page">Pageone</div>
<div id="pagetwo" class="page">Pagetwo</div>
<div id="pagethree" class="page">Pagethree</div>
```

When hitting a div specific to a page, the selected page show, while the others are hidden.

It works fine, but I want a jQuery script more efficient that, when I add any number of pages, works without having to be modified (or at least works without adding a lot more code). The only condition is that it has to use **javascript** and **jQuery** only.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generalized solution like below, instead of using individual handler for each element

```js
var $pages = $('.page');
$pages.slice(1).hide();
$('.trigger').click(function() {
  var $target = $('#' + $(this).data('target')).show();
  $pages.not($target).hide()
});
```

```css
.page {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="trigger" data-target="pageone">Btn one</div>
<div class="trigger" data-target="pagetwo">Btn two</div>
<div class="trigger" data-target="pagethree">Btn three</div>
<div id="pageone" class="page">Pageone</div>
<div id="pagetwo" class="page">Pagetwo</div>
<div id="pagethree" class="page">Pagethree</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have just to use jquery **click()** function, to reduce the code :

**HTML :**

```
<div id="buttonone" data-page='1' class='button'>Btn one</div>
<div id="buttontwo" data-page='2' class='button'>Btn two</div>
<div id="buttonthree" data-page='3' class='button'>Btn three</div>

<div id="page_1" class="page" style='display:block'>Pageone</div>
<div id="page_2" class="page" style='display:none'>Pagetwo</div>
<div id="page_3" class="page" style='display:none'>Pagethree</div>
```

**JS :**

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $('.page').hide();
    $('#page_'+$(this).data('page')).show();
});
```

Find Worked Fiddle **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/o38hvgk1/)**.

Comment: It works. Actually, the third JS row is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery tabs. And you can configure it with tab indexes. For Example;
$("#yourDivName").tabs();
Then you can set which is active on initialization. Which is disabled or enabled, shown or hidden.
You can follow this link;

https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.page:gt(0)').hide();
$('.btn').each(function(){
var $btn = $(this);
var index = $btn.attr('rel');
$btn.click(function () {
    $('.page').hide();
    $('.page[rel="' + index + '"]').show();
});
});
```

```css
.page{
    background:red;
    color:white;
    margin:2em;
    padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div rel="1" class="btn">Btn one</div>
<div rel="2" class="btn">Btn two</div>
<div rel="3" class="btn">Btn three</div>
<div rel="1" class="page">Pageone</div>
<div rel="2" class="page">Pagetwo</div>
<div rel="3" class="page">Pagethree</div>
```

In above example only you have to sync the `rel` attribute.